# Projectile motion with drag

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

first post here :)

So i have a problem to solve projectile motion with drag when drag is linear and quadratic

This is my first take

```
m x''[t] == -k x'[t]
m y''[t] == -m g - k y'[t] 
Movement = 
DSolve[{m x''[t] == -k x'[t], m y''[t] == -m g - k y'[t], x[0] == 0, 
y[0] == 0, x'[0] == Vo Cos[\[Alpha]], 
y'[0] == Vo Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]

Data = {m -> 1, Vo -> 20, g -> 9.81, k -> 0.5, \[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/6, 
tt -> 2}
ParametricPlot[{x[t] /.Movement, y[t] /. Movement} /. Data, {t, 0,
tt /. Data}]
```

It gives a nice graph but im not sure if i made the right assumption for drag-that i can just put it like x'[t] and y[t] in the x and y axis .

This is my second take with

```
v=sqrt[x1'[t]^2 +y1'[t]^2]
m x1''[t] == -k Sqrt[x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2]
m y1''[t] == -m g - k Sqrt[x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2]
Data2 = {m -> .1, Vo -> 10, g -> 9.81, 
k -> 0.001, \[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/6, ttt -> 2}
Movement2 = 
NDSolve[{m x1''[t] == -k Sqrt[x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2], 
m y1''[t] == -m g - k Sqrt[x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2], x1[0] == 0, 
y1[0] == 0, x1'[0] == Vo Cos[\[Alpha]], 
y1'[0] == Vo Sin[\[Alpha]]} /. Data2, {x1, y1}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[{x1[t] /. Movement2, y1[t] /. Movement2}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

This gives me a solution but when i plot it i dont know what am i reading.
How do i combine the solution from NDSolve (x and y ) to get a single line trajectory.(tried parametric plot,didnt work)
Also witch one of these 2 takes is right ?

Edit:Fixed and found the solution for linear drag,now when i enter for quadratig im getting trouble with singularity in NDSolve .

```
Data = {m -> 1, Vo -> 20, g -> 9.81, k -> 0.5, \[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/6, 
tt -> 2}
Movement3 = 
NDSolve[{m x1''[t] == -k x1'[t]^2, m y1''[t] == -m g - k y1'[t]^2, 
x1[0] == 0, y1[0] == 0, x1'[0] == Vo Cos[\[Alpha]], 
y1'[0] == Vo Sin[\[Alpha]]} /. Data, {x1, y1}, {t, 0, 100}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 15, 
MaxSteps -> 20000]
gr2 = ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]} /. Movement2, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I keep getting a singularity that changes as i change the paramateres.Can i fix this somehow? At around 1.217 it hits the ground but when i go beyond that (lets say {t,0,2}) the graph goes bonkers.

And when i try DSolve i get a nicer solution but i have imaginary numbers,how do i plot this solution?

```
Movement3 = 
DSolve[{m x1''[t] == -k x1'[t]^2, m y1''[t] == -m g - k y1'[t]^2, 
x1[0] == 0, y1[0] == 0, x1'[0] == Vo Cos[\[Alpha]], 
y1'[0] == Vo Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {y1[t], x1[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Try this `ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]} /. Movement2, {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: Isn't final time missing?

Comment: Lol it worked,i used it with /.Movement2 inside curly's next to x1 and y1 before. Final time u mean time of landing? havent gotten around to that i wanna get the differential eqations right for both cases.  Thank you :)

Comment: Well,i managed to graph the second one,and its not the same as first one there is a notable difference on range of  the projectile,with same data .Still dont know witch one is right .

Comment: Two different values for `k`. Why you expect that the two output should be the same ?

Comment: i changed them so they use the same data set when i got parametric plot to work

Comment: Also check your physics.  The drag should not always be a negative number.  Shoot the projectile to the left ($\alpha = 5\pi/6$) and the projectile goes a little farther.  That's because the $x$-component of the "drag" is still negative.  Same with the $y$-component.  Also, the $x$-component and the $y$-component of the drag should not be the exact same number.

Comment: I didnt project it in the second case,and when i did i got the first case so i guess the first case was right all along ,the first one shoot same left and right .Thank you that was the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: I urge you to read this [Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/09/27/do-computers-dumb-down-math-education/). It discusses your problem in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second equation is not completely correct. The declaration is proportional to the velocity squared, i.e., $a_d=-kv^2$ but this needs to be properly projected. This means $\boldsymbol{a}_d=-k\,a_d\, \boldsymbol{v}/v=-k\boldsymbol{v} v$ because drag is always oposite to the velocity direction, which is $\boldsymbol{v}/v$.

```
v = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2];
ics = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == Vo Cos[α], 
   y'[0] == Vo Sin[α]};
eqs[1] = {m x''[t] == -k x'[t], m y''[t] == -m g - k  y'[t]};
eqs[2] = {m x''[t] == -k v x'[t], m y''[t] == -m g - k v y'[t]};
eqs[3] = {m x''[t] == -k v , m y''[t] == -m g - k v };
sys[i_] := Join[eqs[i], ics, {WhenEvent[y[t] <= 0, y'[t] -> 0.01]}];
data = {m -> .1, Vo -> 100, g -> 9.81, 
   k -> 0.001, α -> Pi/6};
move = Table[
   First@NDSolve[sys[i] /. data, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}], {i, 3}];
gr = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[({x[t], y[t]} /. move)], {t, 0, 10}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The 1st case is drag linearly proportional to the velocity, 2nd is the quadratic drag, while 3rd is your original formula. Finally, the particle collides with the "ground". Therefore the `WhenEvent`.

I wonder though why `AspectRatio` is not working as expected and why the propagation slows down if in `WhenEven` I reduce the reflection velocity to 0.00001. Can someone improve my answer?

Comment: Thank you,so when you project the quadratic drag on x it goes  -k * [v^2 * x'[t])^2 * x'[t]/v ) ,the x'[t]/v is the cos of angle for x axis ,?just checking need to be sure :)

Comment: @AndrejLicanin Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `Movement2` variable, it is a 1x2 array. Then you look at `x1[t] /. Movement2`, it returns a list. Plot[ ] handles this, ParametricPlot[ ] does not. So just grab the first (and only) item from the list. Add this to your code above:

```
ParametricPlot[{(x1[t] /. Movement2) // First, (y1[t] /. Movement2) //
First}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

EDIT: although I like @zhk 's answer better. In general, got to keep an eye on your list-ology.